# Generic Custom STACK Class for Hanoi Problem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, stack, queue

I have created a custom class (Generic) in C# for the [Hanoi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi). and I am not sure I did the correct thing.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
    public class HanoiStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable where T : IHanoiStack
    {
        private T[] _array;     // Storage for stack elements
        private int _size;           // Number of items in the stack.
        private int _version;        // Used to keep enumerator in sync w/ collection.
        private Object _syncRoot;

        private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
        static T[] _emptyArray = new T[0];

        public HanoiStack()
        {
            _array = _emptyArray;
            _size = 0;
            _version = 0;
        }

        public HanoiStack(int capacity)
        {
            if (capacity < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Negative Value Exception");
            _array = new T[capacity];
            _size = 0;
            _version = 0;
        }

        public HanoiStack(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            if (collection == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Null Collection");

            ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
            if (c != null)
            {
                int count = c.Count;
                _array = new T[count];
                c.CopyTo(_array, 0);
                _size = count;
            }
            else
            {
                _size = 0;
                _array = new T[_defaultCapacity];

                using (IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (en.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Push(en.Current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _size; }
        }

        bool System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        Object System.Collections.ICollection.SyncRoot
        {
            get
            {
                if (_syncRoot == null)
                {
                    System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Object>(ref _syncRoot, new Object(), null);
                }
                return _syncRoot;
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            Array.Clear(_array, 0, _size);
            _size = 0;
            _version++;
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            int count = _size;

            EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            while (count-- > 0)
            {
                if (((Object)item) == null)
                {
                    if (((Object)_array[count]) == null)
                        return true;
                }
                else if (_array[count] != null && c.Equals(_array[count], item))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Null Array");
            }

            if (arrayIndex < 0 || arrayIndex > array.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Negative Argument Exception");
            }

            if (array.Length - arrayIndex < _size)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Argument");
            }

            Array.Copy(_array, 0, array, arrayIndex, _size);
            Array.Reverse(array, arrayIndex, _size);
        }

        void System.Collections.ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Array Null Exception");
            }

            if (array.Rank != 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Rank Multiple Supported");
            }

            if (array.GetLowerBound(0) != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Negative Value Exception");
            }

            if (arrayIndex < 0 || arrayIndex > array.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Negative Value Exception");
            }

            if (array.Length - arrayIndex < _size)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Argument");
            }

            try
            {
                Array.Copy(_array, 0, array, arrayIndex, _size);
                Array.Reverse(array, arrayIndex, _size);
            }
            catch (ArrayTypeMismatchException)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument Invalid Exception");
            }
        }

        public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }

        public void TrimExcess()
        {
            int threshold = (int)(((double)_array.Length) * 0.9);
            if (_size < threshold)
            {
                T[] newarray = new T[_size];
                Array.Copy(_array, 0, newarray, 0, _size);
                _array = newarray;
                _version++;
            }
        }

        public T Peek()
        {
            if (_size == 0)
                throw new Exception("Stack Hanoi is Empty");
            return _array[_size - 1];
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            if (_size == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack Hanoi is Empty");
            _version++;
            T item = _array[--_size];
            _array[_size] = default(T);     // Free memory quicker.
            return item;
        }

        public void Push(T item)
        {
            if (_size > 0)
            {
                var _newItem = (IHanoiStack)item;
                var _currentItem = (IHanoiStack)this.Peek();
                if (_currentItem.Height > _newItem.Height)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Height of the previous item is lesser than the new item.");
                }
                if (_currentItem.Weigth > _newItem.Weigth)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Weigth of the previous item is lesser than the new item.");
                }
            }
            if (_size == _array.Length)
            {

                T[] newArray = new T[(_array.Length == 0) ? _defaultCapacity : 2 * _array.Length];
                Array.Copy(_array, 0, newArray, 0, _size);
                _array = newArray;
            }
            _array[_size++] = item;
            _version++;
        }

        public T[] ToArray()
        {
            T[] objArray = new T[_size];
            int i = 0;
            while (i < _size)
            {
                objArray[i] = _array[_size - i - 1];
                i++;
            }
            return objArray;
        }

        public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>,
            System.Collections.IEnumerator
        {
            private HanoiStack<T> _stack;
            private int _index;
            private int _version;
            private T currentElement;

            internal Enumerator(HanoiStack<T> stack)
            {
                _stack = stack;
                _version = _stack._version;
                _index = -2;
                currentElement = default(T);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _index = -1;
            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                bool retval;
                if (_version != _stack._version) throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack Hanoi is Empty");
                if (_index == -2)
                {  // First call to enumerator.
                    _index = _stack._size - 1;
                    retval = (_index >= 0);
                    if (retval)
                        currentElement = _stack._array[_index];
                    return retval;
                }
                if (_index == -1)
                {  // End of enumeration.
                    return false;
                }

                retval = (--_index >= 0);
                if (retval)
                    currentElement = _stack._array[_index];
                else
                    currentElement = default(T);
                return retval;
            }

            public T Current
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_index == -2) throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumNotStarted");
                    if (_index == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumEnded");
                    return currentElement;
                }
            }

            Object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_index == -2) throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumNotStarted");
                    if (_index == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumEnded");
                    return currentElement;
                }
            }

            void System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
            {
                if (_version != _stack._version) throw new InvalidOperationException("EnumFailedVersion");
                _index = -2;
                currentElement = default(T);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IHanoiStack
    {
        double Height { get; }
        double Weigth { get; }
    }
```

I am trying to use a Generic class for the Hanoi problem. it might be simple for some of you. but I have created this in learning the C# Generics. Please help me to validate the code.

1. The Hanoi problem.
   This will have a stack of disks of size (n) on a pole and it should be shifted to another among the 3 poles available. But the disks should be in the same order as they were on the previous pole. (Correct?)
2. I kind of thought that the "STACK" would help me but it will allow the user to add items in any order. So I created an interface that has Width and Height of the Disk so that I could validate the order based on that Interface.
3. I have a question here, is this the correct way to do this or I was wrong.

Comment: Am I incorrect to assume that this is a slightly modified version of the .NET BCL class `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>`? I don't believe we should provide a review for this code, because you are not in a position to justify the design decisions that lead to most all of it.

Comment: @VisualMelon To me it looked like a java version trying to be ported to C#.

Comment: @dfhwze see [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs). It's essentially the same. (Which the OP has just confirmed)

Comment: @VisualMelon wow, that's a lame thing to do.

Comment: @VisualMelon ,  as I mentioned below I am just trying to learn Generics in C#. I browsed the Microsoft reference source and find the link I have specified. and wrote the logic on top of it.

Comment: The whole point of generics is that you don't need to create type-specific copies of the same logic. If you need a stack that can only store `IHanoiStack` objects, then `var hanoiStack = new Stack<IHanoiStack>()` is all you need to do.

Comment: @NavinKumarKSubramanian it's fine to do whatever you want to aid your learning; however, not everything should be posted on CodeReview. You might want to visit the [help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see how best to use the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have created a simpler version. I have removed my review of the code not written by you.

```
 public class HanoiStack<T> : Stack<T> where T : IHanoiElement
    {
        public new void Push(T item)
        {
            // null checks ..
            if (Count != 0)
            {
                var top = this.Peek();
                if (item.Height > top.Height || item.Weigth > top.Weigth)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The item is too big");
                }
            }
            base.Push(item);
        }
    }

    public interface IHanoiElement
    {
        double Height { get; }
        double Weigth { get; }
    }
```

---

### Naming Conventions

I would not call the element type `IHanoiStack` a stack, rather an element `IHanoiElement`.

> ```
>  public interface IHanoiStack
>     {
>         double Height { get; }
>         double Weigth { get; }
>     }
> ```

Comment: I tried it but since I was learning C# Generics. I just went through in this website so I replicated the same in my code. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6